# Conditional variable declaration in golang?

Tags: go

Is it possible to do conditional variable type declaration like this in Golang?

```
if isAdmin {
  var result NormalResult
} else {
  var result AdminResult
}

// do something to &result
doSomething(&result)

func doSomething(interface{}) {
  // something
}
```

The above does not work, but the ideas is that normalResult and adminResults are very similar structs and how would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: That depends on what your result types look like. Can you give examples?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. Can you give a real world example ?

Comment: Looks like a code smell: try to think about your problem and how to design the solution more cleanly; your current approach can easily lead to hard to read and/or error-prone code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what kind of similarities, you might have different options.

**Using embedded structs**

Depending on your structure, you might be able to use embedded structs. Let's say NormalResult is defined like this:

```
type NormalResult struct {
    Name  string
    Value int
}
```

And if AdminResult shares the same properties but just adds a few more of them (like UserId), you can choose to embed NormalResult into the AdminResult like this:

```
type AdminResult struct {
    *NormalResult
    UserId int64
}
```

Then you can also declare methods for `NormalResult` which will be promoted to AdminResult as well:

```
func (r *NormalResult) doSomething() {
    // Doing something
}
```

**Edit**
And, no, it is not possible to have conditional types in Go as you suggested. A variable can only be of one type, be it `NormalResult`, `AdminResult` or `interface{}`

Comment: Moving `doSomething` to the implementation of the struct is a good idea. The other option would've been to use interfaces to abstract the result type but I like this one better. Also, who votes this down with no comment?

Comment: Yes, first I thought about using interface abstraction, but with embedding you only have to implement the interface for `NormalResult` and both structs will have implemented it. So it is still an option.

Answer (score 12):

No, not in this manner. Go being statically typed, needs to know the type information at compile time.

What you could do is declare `result` as an interface of some type which both AdminResult and NormalResult satisfy. You can then use a type assertion at runtime to decide which type of result it is.

(You also have to declare `result` outside of the if blocks because Go is block scoped)

```
type NormalResult struct {
    Value int
}

func (r NormalResult) Result() int {
    return r.Value
}

type AdminResult struct {
    Value int
}

func (r AdminResult) Result() int {
    return r.Value
}

type Resulter interface {
    Result() int
}

func main() {
    isAdmin := true
    var r Resulter

    if isAdmin {
        r = AdminResult{2}
    } else {
        r = NormalResult{1}
    }

    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", r)

}
```

Comment: Personally, I would use the version @ANisus suggested as you won't need to unpack the interface and do type assertions and so forth.

Comment: @nemo, as would I, but if the OP really needed to use distinct type for some reason, this would be a way to do it.

Comment: fmt.Println("Hello, playground", r.Result())